# issue in angular nav bar with routing

Tags: angular, navbar

I am working on sidenavbar in angular i have set path in app-routing.module.ts and gave the routing path to my nav bar but im not able to load the content from add-emp.component.html can anyone help me fix this ? and thank you in advance

**code** 
app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AddEmpComponent } from './components/add-emp/add-emp.component';



const routes: Routes = [
  
  { path: 'add', component: AddEmpComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

main-nav.component.html

```
  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/add']">add</a>
    
   </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>navform</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a slash infront of link

```
<a mat-list-item routerLink='/add'>add</a>
```

Comment: i tried but not able to display the content though it is going to http://localhost:4200/add

Answer (score 0):

If you want the router looks up the route from the root of the app. Adding `/` at the beginning of the path.

```
<mat-nav-list>
   <a mat-list-item routerLink="/add">add</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

**or:**

```
<mat-nav-list>
   <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/add']">add</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: I tried this its going to this http://localhost:4200/add but not able to display text from add-emp.component.html

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue on stackblitz? Or you could paste more of code

Comment: Maybe you can tried it on stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts